# Restrict files from CDN in Content Security Policy

Tags: cdn, cloudflare, content-security-policy

Suppose there are **A,B,C,D** and **E** js files present in a CDN but we are using only **B** and **C**.
Currently *script-src* in csp allows **all js** files being downloaded from that CDN but I want to restrict the download only to **B** and **C** for my application?
Can this be done in Content security policy configuration?

```
<add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com />
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **pathes** in the Content Security Policy (path should have a trailing slash). For example:

   script-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/;

does allow to load any script frim the specified path, for instance `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js` or `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js`,
but not `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.6.1/jquery.js`.

2. You can specify an **exact file name** like:

   script-src cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js;

this will allow the specified script only.

> 

Pls keep in mind that above can be bypassed if you web app (or CDN) allows open redirect, because CSP does not checks pathes in case of redirects. So:

```
<script src='https://your_domain.com.com/?redirect=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.4/vue.js'>
```

will allow to load vue.js script.